# Amcharts Serial: How to get current zoom indexes

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In the amcharts serial chart you can select a specific area of values to display using this function:

```
chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - x, chartData.length - 1)
```

This displays the last x values.
However, this selected area can be changed by the user dragging the chart cursor.
So if i would want to save the last indexes the chart was zoomed to before leaving the page / doing whatever, how can i get them?

The documentation does not seem to provide any helpful information here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed these in the documentation.

[startIndex](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#startIndex) - gives you a read-only value of the current start zoom index.

[endIndex](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#endIndex) - gives you a read-only value of the current end zoom index.

They are accessible through the chart instance. For example, here's how to access them during the [zoomed](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomed) event:

```
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "zoomed",
    "method": function(e) { 
      console.log('Start zoom index: ', e.chart.startIndex,  'End zoom index: ', e.chart.endIndex);
    }
  }]
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1e5a8200b1cd67f8c764818e517e48e5)

Comment: to access the indices outside an event, use `chart.start` and `chart.end`, you can see these properties when you print the object to the console

Comment: While you *could* do that, it's not recommended as those are internal properties and, thus, not meant for public use. `startIndex` and `endIndex` are available outside of the event as well.

Comment: can we set the zoom to these indices when the data of the chart is updated?

Comment: Yes. Use the [`dataUpdated`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#dataUpdated) event.